# Connection to database is taking too much time [pyodbc]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I want to access my MSSQL database using python.

I wrote a simple script to access just 1 row from my database table.

Funnily enough it is taking around 12 seconds to only connect to my database. (which I found quite alot for a simple connect)

Am I doing something wrong?

```
import pyodbc
import time
import config

connect_start = time.time()

dsn = f'Driver=SQL Server;Server={config.sql["server"]};Database={config.sql["database"]};User={config.sql["user_id"]};Password={config.sql["password"]}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(dsn)
print(f'Connect time: {time.time() - connect_start}')

cursor_start = time.time()

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM [ytviewer].[dbo].[tbl_provider]')
print(f'Cursor execution time: {time.time() - cursor_start}')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Output:
Connect time: 12.036243677139282

Cursor execution time: 0.0

(1, 'Pldown')

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using an incorrect driver to connect.

This is the one I had to use: Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server